# QGIS Temporal controller: getting the current animation time (percentage elapsed of total animation duration) with expressions / variables

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, animation, temporal-controller

**The question**

How can I get the current animation time of a Temporal Controller animation using expressions with QGIS 3.24? I guess I'm almost there (see below), but have trouble dividing a time formatted as `interval` by a number.

**The background (what I need it for)**

I finally want to get a value that shows what percentage of the whole animation has elapsed at a certain frame. I want to use this value to style a line layer with geometry generator, using [line_substring()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#line-substring) function to draw the same percentage of the line's total length as the percentage of time elapsed: so at the beginning, 0% of the line, after 30% of the whole animation the first 30% of the line's lenght etc. Like this, I could animate the line without creating interpolated points with timestamps (what would be a workaround) by activating Dynamic Temporal Contral in the layer properties with Configuration `Redraw Layer Only`.

The expression to create this would look like: `line_substring( $geometry, 0, $length * [percentage] )` - where `[percentage]` is the value I'm trying to create.

**What I tried**

My idea was to the get the total length of the whole anmimation with `@animation_end_time - @animation_start_time`. This return a time interval (like `<interval: 10.375 minutes>`). Unfortunately, there is no variable like `@animation_current_time` that returns the time of the current frame.

There is, however, the variable `@frame_number` that returns the current frame number during animation playback. The variables `@frame_timestep` and `@frame_duration` return the temporal duration of each animation frame.

**Example**

Let's say I have the following values. A total time of 24 frames * 8 seconds = 192 seconds have elapsed, that is 30.8% of the total animation time of 10.375 minutes:

- Total length of animation: `<interval: 10.375 minutes>` ( = `@animation_end_time - @animation_start_time`)
- Current frame number: `24` ( = `@frame_number`)
- Temporal duration of each animation frame: `8` (using `@frame_timestep`) or `<interval: 8 seconds>` (with `@frame_duration`)
- **What I want to get (pseudocode): `<current-time> / <total-duration> -> 0.308 (30.8%)`**

So how to divide `<interval: 10.375 minutes>` by the time elapsed : 192 (`@frame_number * @frame_timestep`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the percentage by using an expression such as:

```
second(datetime_from_epoch(epoch(to_datetime(to_string("mytime")+'Z')) - epoch(@animation_start_time)) - make_datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)) / second(@animation_interval)
```

Be aware of the timezones! Seems like QGIS temporal-controller-variables always work with UTC, while your datetime may be in another timezone. You can correct this by adding or subtracting the hour difference in seconds. Or a little more elegant change the 0-time of `make_datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)` to e.g. `make_datetime(1970,1,1,1,0,0)` In my example above I had to manually set UTC as timezone, thats why I use `to_string("mytime")+'Z'`. Remove that part if you dont need it!

Example result:

[image]

Comment: Converting the time to seconds was what solved my problem. As I have no date, only time, I don't have to care about time zones. So the expression that worked for me looks like:

`line_substring( 
 $geometry, 
 0, 
 $length * 
 @frame_timestep * @frame_number /
 second (@animation_end_time - @animation_start_time)
)`